# update list element in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list of maps as one field of a DynamoDB table. How can I update a specific element (or, rather element field ?)
Trying something like

```
rc = table.update_item(Key={ 'username' : user }, 
    UpdateExpression="set list[:i].field = :nd",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':i' : itemnum,
        ':nd': data,
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
);
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: ":i", near: "[:i]"
```

Any ideas how can I reference list element with variable number. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a literal instead:

```
rc = table.update_item(Key={ 'username' : user }, 
    UpdateExpression="set list[" + itemnum + "].field = :nd",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':nd': data,
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to find the item by ID, and not by index? I have a list such as

[{id: "111", rating: "4"},{id: "112", rating: "5"}]

Comment: @Balaji no, it's not available

Comment: Does this have any security risk if itemnum is send by the end user?

Comment: @Snedden27 it's up to you to vet user input, making sure they can update the item at the given position.

Comment: Ew, json injection

Comment: @scott.korin looking forward to see your own answer to the problem

Comment: @AndréWerlang I think the other answer solves the problem by forcing itemnum to be an int.  ...I think.

Comment: @scott.korin the problem you refer to is usually associated with user input, and typecasting to a number is just one requirement, there are others. Also we have to work with the API provided by the vendor. The other answer is just a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer to @Snedden27 "Does this have any security risk if itemnum is send by the end user?"

Yes, in theory a user could inject something here in certain circumstances (e.g. if you are updating a list and the list items are also lists then the user could input "3][2" which would make a valid expression that updates a nested list and screws up your data structure.

Something like parseInt on the input should prevent this injection:

```
rc = table.update_item(Key={ 'username' : user }, 
    UpdateExpression="set parent_list[" + parseInt(itemnum) + "] = :nd",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':nd': child_list,
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
);
```